# Angular 2 application deployed on JBOSS 6.4 eap with java services as backend

Tags: java, angular, jboss6.x

Problem 1: Angular 2 application deployed on JBOSS server but not able to load static content (js/css). The problem is the website is hosted under its own context (localhost:8080/sample/) and static resources is refered in index.html as (link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet") however it doesnt get loaded as network calls are made to localhost:8080/css/index.css.

I need it to point to localhost:8080/sample/css/index.css

Problem 2: Alternately we tried hosting angular application on tomcat but services need to be hosted on jboss, we tried implementing CROS filter (https://amodernstory.com/2014/12/27/using-cors-headers-with-java-example/) but the first request goes through but other request shows pending status in Chrome network's tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having the same problem. To get it to load the static content, you need to set the base href inside index.html to "./". I have found that "." also works. The application should then load properly, BUT you will run into another problem: if you try to visit any of the application routes directly using the address bar, you will see "Not Found". This seems to be related to JBoss's ability to rewrite HTML5 URLs and redirect them to the index. I am trying to solve that problem using the information on this page: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JDF-512. I will let you know if I succeed.

Comment: Thanks Mate, Solution for adding "./" in base href of index.html worked for me. but now facing another issue that i am not getting response from webapi when deployed in jboss 6.4, however it is working fine in tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an index.prod.html with the correct references to "/sample/css/index.css". Then add the following in the angular.json

```
"production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/index.html",
              "with": "src/index.prod.html"
            }
```